# SQL: Average number of applications per customer for last x months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables Customer, Applications, ApplicationHistory. I have to retrieve following data:

1. Get the average number of applications per customer for last 3 months
2. Get the number of customers with atleast one or more applications for last 3 months

I had been trying group by however having following issues:

- ApplicationHistory table has more than one entries for each application, now sure how to eliminate them  &
- Note: Have included Customer Table as need to filter data by customertype

Can you please suggest how can I get this right?

Many thanks,

> My Solution ( does not work )

```
SELECT a.ApplicationId, a.CustomerId,  count(*) count                           
from [application] a
inner join [applicationhistory] ah on a.ApplicationId = ah.ApplicationId
inner join Customer c  on c.CustomerId = a.CustomerId
where  ah.EventDate between @StartDateFilter and @EndDateFilter 
       --c.CustomerType in ( A, B)
group by a.ApplicationId, a.CustomerId
```

> Table Structure:

```
Customer
Name  CustomerId   CustomerType
test1   1               A
test2   2               B

Applications
ApplicationId  CustomerId
3                   1
4                   1
5                   2                
6                   2                
7                   2                

ApplicationHistory
ApplicationId   EventDate         EventType
3               2014-12-01           New
3               2014-12-01           Updated
3               2014-12-02           Withdrawn
4               2014-12-02           New
4               2014-12-03           Updated
5               2014-12-05           New
5               2014-12-06           Updated
5               2014-12-06           Updated
5               2014-12-07           Updated
6               2014-12-08           New
```

Comment: Do you define "average number of applications" as ApplicationHistories with an EventType of "New" in the given timeframe or any EventType?

Comment: @Bernd: "Average number of applications" would be average of applications count in Applications table for a customer. Also fyi, system creates a row in ApplicationHistory table for each change made by customer, i.e. New Application, Update in Application & so on. And in order to apply date filter I have to use this ApplicationHistory table in query, as it has more than one rows for each application ( for different event types ), I am not able to get around this.

Comment: Edit your question with sample data.  The `Applications` table, as you have defined it, does not have an "applications count".  You can get the total number of applications, but the average doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Gordon:  Sorry for the confusion, what I meant is : "Average number of applications" would be average of number of applications for a customer in Applications table

Comment: @Maverick . . . That still doesn't make sense.  Please edit the question with the results you want.  You can get a "Total".  An "Average" doesn't make sense, unless you want something like an average per month.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : I will try to give information on the context. Suppose for last 3 months, one customer has 10 applications, 2nd customer has 20 applications,  3rd customer has 30 applications. Then average number of applications per customer would be (10+20+30) / 3 = 20 , Hope this make sense now.

Comment: Any suggestions ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you query doesn't need the joins -- unless you care about customers with no applications.  So, this is a simpler version to get the total

```
select ah.CustomerId, count(*) as cnt                           
from applicationhistory ah
where  ah.EventDate between @StartDateFilter and @EndDateFilter 
group by a.CustomerId;
```

Note that the `group by` only has `CustomerId` and not `ApplicationId`.

If you want only "New" applications, the use `where`:

```
select ah.CustomerId, count(*) as cnt                           
from applicationhistory ah
where ah.EventDate between @StartDateFilter and @EndDateFilter and
      EventType = 'New'
group by a.CustomerId;
```

If you want net applications "new" - "withdrawn", then use conditional aggregation:

```
select ah.CustomerId,
       sum(case when EventType = 'New' then 1 else -1 end) as cnt                   
from applicationhistory ah
where ah.EventDate between @StartDateFilter and @EndDateFilter and
      EventType in ( 'New', 'Withdrawn' )
group by a.CustomerId;
```

Comment: Gordon: thanks a lot for your answer , and apologies I made a horrible mistake in my question. ApplicatioryHistory does not have CustomerId column ( updated my question ).  So I would need to join with Applications table. And additionally I need to filter by a specific customer type that's why I needed to join with Customer table as well.